# Using Flask-Assets with Flask-Mako

Tags: python, flask, mako, webassets

I would like to use flask-assets to organize my webassets and mako for templating. Flask-assets normally uses jinja in the following way:

```
{% assets "js_all" %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
{% endassets %}
```

The Mako equivalent (as far as I know) would be the following:

```
    % assets 'coffee':
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
    % endassets
```

However this causes a compile error:

```
mako.exceptions.CompileException
CompileException: Unsupported control keyword: 'assets' in file '/index.html' at line: 8 char: 1
```

Is there any way to use custom control keywords (like 'assets') in Mako?

Here is my app.py for the record:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext import assets
from flask import config
from flask.ext.mako import MakoTemplates
from flask.ext.mako import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['ASSETS_DEBUG'] = True

mako = MakoTemplates(app)
env = assets.Environment(app)

# Tell flask-assets where to look for our coffeescript and sass files.
env.load_path = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'js'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'styles'),
]

coffee = assets.Bundle('**/*.coffee', filters='coffeescript', output="app.js")
env.register('coffee', coffee)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', name='mako')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I came up with a solution. You can make it work by importing the environment into your base template and acting on that.

assets.py:

```
import os
from flask.ext import assets
from app import app

env = assets.Environment(app)

# Tell flask-assets where to look for our coffeescript and sass files.
env.load_path = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'js'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'styles'),
]

coffee = assets.Bundle('**/*.coffee', filters='coffeescript', output="app.js")
env.register('coffee', coffee)
```

Template:

```
<%!
  from assets import env
%>

<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello Flask</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello Flask</h1>

        % for url in env['coffee'].urls():
            <script src="${url}"></script>
        % endfor

    </body>
</html>
```

There might be way to avoid the import by using the MAKO_IMPORTS config parameter but I haven't played with it.

Answer (score 1):

Flask-Assets simply [registers the webassets Jinja extension with Flask's Jinja environment](https://github.com/miracle2k/flask-assets/blob/018296e3a3ea40df15fb2b27bed80fd405133c2c/src/flask_assets.py#L328-330).  WebAssets only ships (at the time of this writing) [with an extension for Jinja2](http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/jinja2.html), so if you want an assets tag for Mako you will have [to write one yourself](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html#defs-with-content) (although someone has [already written something similar for Pyramid](https://github.com/sontek/pyramid_webassets#mako), so you may be able to [take inspiration from that](https://github.com/sontek/pyramid_webassets/blob/65f7f8539b2e1c88c528a0350d430f92770de2c8/pyramid_webassets/__init__.py#L346-368)).